# Criterion for existence of solution to nonlinear second order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Good day.  I am asking this question as an issue of concern for determining whether an ordinary differential equation can be solved.  Existence, and not uniqueness of solution, is what is required.  Assume we are able to obtain a second order O.D.E in the form $f(u'',u',u, x) = 0$ where $f$ is continuous in all its arguments on an interval $I$. Is this sufficient to justify existence of a solution $u(x)$ to the O.D.E on $I$? If further details on the O.D.E are required, please let me know.

Comment: No. Take for example the equation $(u'')^2+1=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Complex analytic solutions are not disallowed for this purpose.  Anyway, if the condition I placed is insufficient, please let me in on any necessary and sufficient conditions for solvability.

Comment: How about $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u''}\neq 0$.